# Unexpected default kerning when using attributedText of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield, kerning

I would like to create grouping with kerning in a UITextField. I use `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method to be able to react to every text change. I format my text then assign it back to the `attributedText` property of the textfield. It works great but I have a small bug which I don't understand. When I leave the cursor after a character which has different kerning (lets say 4) then the default (around 1) and the textfield loses the focus that default kerning changes to the one which was before the cursor (4). Any idea why is this happening? How to solve this problem nicely?

[image: Focus loss]

I have noticed that if I nil out the property `selectedTextRange` in `textFieldShouldEndEditing` then this bug disappears but It just doesn't seem nice to implement this method just because of this.

Source code of this ViewController can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ngeri/0080d429a0b6d195eeff3f54dafb0c11).